# Understanding an existence problem in terms of functions.

Tags: functions, soft-question, alternative-proof

Working on the book: Daniel J. Velleman. "HOW TO PROVE IT: A Structured Approach, Second Edition" (p. 150)

> Example 3.6.3. Prove that for every real number $x$, if $x \neq 2$ then there is a unique real number $y$ such that $2y/(y + 1) = x$.

My questions:

- Is it possible to rephrase it in terms of functions ?
- Am I asked to show that the function $f(x)=2x/(x + 1)$ (domain: $\mathbb{R}-\{2\}$) has range = $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: You are being asked to show that there is a function $g:\{2\}^c \to \mathbb{R}$ such that ${2 g(x) \over g(x)+1} = x$.

Comment: you are basically being asked to find a solution for $\frac{2y}{y+1} = x$ where $x $ is different from 2, because if $x$ equals $2$, you'll get  $0 = 2$. you can solve for y in the equation and you'll get the result. If you want to rephrase it in terms of a function.  you can do it like this, $f(t) = \frac{2t}{t+1} - x$ and prove that for any x different than 2, the function has a unique zero

Comment: Thanks both of you. @copper.hat, what's this $\{2\}^c$ ?

Comment: The complement of 2.

Comment: Thank you, @copper.hat. Could you give me a hint about finding that function $g$ ?

Comment: Have you tried solving the equation for $y$ in terms of $x$?

Comment: Yes, I found $y=\frac{x}{2-x}$. But you rephrasing of the problem seems very interesting :-)

Comment: For your final question, you are being asked to show that the *range* of $f$ is $\Bbb R \setminus \{2\}$ (or $\{2\}^c$). The domain of $f$ is easily seen to be $\Bbb R \setminus \{-1\}$.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Paul Sinclair. That's exactly what I wanted to know. I appreciate it.